# Room : How migration with fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom() works?

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app with room database version 1 up and running . At version 2  , I want to destroy all the tables and recreate schema instead of writing `Migration(1, 2)` logic . So I read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigrationfrom) and found method `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom()` . So if I pass 2 in argument here then I think it should recreate all tables at
version 2 . The thing I cannot under stand is In docs they mentioned a note

> Note: No versions passed to this method may also exist as either starting or ending versions in the Migrations provided to addMigrations(Migration). If a version passed to this method is found as a starting or ending version in a Migration, an exception will be thrown

Does this mean If I upgrade database version to 3 and there are some schema changes , If I write `Migration(2, 3)` it will throw an exception ?

Comment: have you tried it ?  :)

Comment: No , I will give it a try once I am free . Even if it does not throw and exception , I cannot risk writing .

Comment: that's fair, I was just think does sound like something you could potentially try yourself, at least as a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct if you pass `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(3)` and also provide `Migration(2, 3)`, Room will throw an exception.

That said it does sound like what you really want to do is use `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`.
In this case, it will do exactly what you asked:

1. Try to upgrade from version X (installed on the device) to version Y
2. If there is no `Migration(X, Y)` it will destroy the schema and data
   and create a new one for version Y.

In this way, you should not get an exception.
I think that is what you were asking for...

Comment: No `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` will destroy data if migration strategy is wrong . I want it to throw an exception if migration logic is wrong and only destroy database at version 2

Comment: In that case use fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(2). You can pass a set of versions to fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom and Room will check this set before it tries to migrate. If the DB version was in that set it will not try to migrate it but just destroy it instead. For every other version it will throw an exception if it will not find a migration.

Comment: But if I upgraded my database to version 3 in future and write `Migration(2, 3)` won't  it throw an exception as per documents

Comment: yes, it will throw an exception. If you create, in the future, Migration(2, 3) you'll have to remove the  fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(2). You cannot eat the cake and leave it whole :)

Comment: Then what if a user is migrating from 1 to 3 ? Suppose he did not update his app at 2 .

Comment: if you have Migration(1, 3)  and fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(2) it will work fine. Because Room only does what you explicitly tell it to do. In this case it will only destroy the schema of V2 databases

Comment: also if you did not supply Migration(1, 3), in my previouse comment you will get an exception becuase Room will not know what to do with V1 database users. It cannot destroy the data and it cannot migrate to V3 so it will throw an exception

Comment: so you expect to write all migrations from version 1  (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)... ?  I don't think this is the right answer

Comment: No, You should write (1,3) (3,4) (4,5) . If you want to kill V2. if not then just (1,2)(2,3)(3,4)....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199235/discussion-between-manohar-reddy-and-itamar-kerbel).

Answer (score 4):

Every thing I said in the Question was right except that I had to pass 1 as argument to `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom()` .

`.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1)` would mean to destroy database if the old database version is 1 . Its not like destroy database if the current version is 1 . This was the confusion in my case .

Credit to [Itamar Kerbel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866685/6478047) for the clarification in the chat .